# C# Elastic Beanstalk webapp , could not find a base address that matches scheme https for endpoint with webhttpbinding.

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ssl, https

Basically I want to create a https secure Restful WCF service. So, I am using webhttpbinding for my services since it supports creation of RESTful services. Preferably I would have wanted to do it with a single instance EBS but EBS doesn't support SSL cert. config in C#/.net platforms, so I set up a load balancer, uploaded my cert to IAM and opened listeners on the ELB. But no matter what I do, my web.config doesn't seem to work. Could you please help me figure out my web.config...`

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="webHttpBinding_ICustomerService" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
                <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:44300/CustomerService/CustomerService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfService2.ICustomerService"
            name="" kind="" endpointConfiguration="" />
    </client>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_ICustomerService"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" contract="WcfService2.ICustomerService">
            <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
            </endpoint>
          <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="mex"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="https://example.com/" />
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're using basicHttpsBinding on your endpoint while providing an http:// address, which would result in the mismatched scheme error.

Comment: No help, even when I change it makes not difference, I get the same error.  <client></client> is for the local wcf client anyway, shouldn't matter after I deploy it to Beanstalk.